# Sending mail from java code - the reliable way

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, apache-commons

It's a pretty common thing to have to send mails from your app and in most cases it's a real pain in the ... you know where.

So what I'm doing is taking Apache Commons Email (which is based on top of the "official" java mail api) and I'm sending out email in the most simple way there is, i.e. without authenticating to a smtp server. I just do a simple MX lookup on the destination hostname, get the MX servers and try to drop my message at the first one (whether the mail gets rejected or not is a completely different issue and I might sometime soon ask a further question about the whole mess up with return-path: vs. from: vs. reply-to: and the way these headers are (not) handled in java). Back to business... So I've just tried to drop my Message at the mail server with the least preference score.

Here is an example: I want to write to `recipient@domain.com`. The MX Lookup tells me that `domain.com` is aware of two MX servers and these are e.g. `mail1.domain.com` with preference 10 and `mail2.domain.com` with preference 20. The rfc way to do things is to go to the server with the least preference and drop the mail there. So that's what I do.

And finally my problem: What happens if that server is not available in some way or another? It's pretty simple - I go to the other server, but Apache Commons (and I suspect java mail api) doesn't allow me to do just that. The `mail.smtp.host` variable is rooted inside the props of the session in the message in the email. And I cannot get at it.

So what's the best way to handle this problem? Should I build my Email completely from the top with the new hostname (mail2), or is there some clever way to make this all work in java without much pain?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds if you are trying to implement a partial mail server, not just merely sending an e-mail. Routing, relaying, caching and delivery retrials are operations implemented and offered by all mail servers and not usually done by mail clients.

What you should do is either use an (one!) existing mail server, which is configured for you to allow relaying outbound mails or if you don't have access to such a server (which I doubt), setup and operate your own server. You then configure *this* server in `mail.smtp.host` and forget all you've learned about DNS lookups, server priorities and your worries about what to do if none of the MX servers are reachable.

Comment: yeah, I've considered using `aspirin` or even `james` or even a fully functional "external" SMTP server (but in the latter case each client would have to set up his own smtp server, and that is really way to much to ask from a client these days :) ), but it seems too much of an overkill to solve such a simple problem. Or maybe just my notions of "simple" and "overkill" are skewed :)

Comment: I don't know where your software is supposed to run or which kind of clients you are talking about, but if your software is required to send outgoing mails, it is IMHO not too much demanded to be provided with a running SMTP server. Companies have an SMTP server running anyway and which home user doesn't have access to an SMTP server from either their Internet access provider or "pure" mail providers like GMail or Hotmail?

Comment: I agree, use an existing email server.  If you still want to do this yourself, you might need to use the JavaMail API directly so you can use the Transport.connect method to connect directly to whatever server you want.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with you both. And yet I've got my requirements and can't go that way (believe me, I've tried arguing that an existing SMTP server should be used). Still I want to do things the right(ish) way. @BillShannon Apache Commons Mail actually handles both `com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport` and `javax.mail.Transport` quite nicely. Please note that it's not impossible to do what I want, it just seems a bit ugly to me (wait for an exception, if one is caught create a new message and try dropping it by at the next MX host, etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure I see another way.  You're effectively implementing the sending half of an SMTP server in your application.